# SQL, c# WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I need help with sql and C#. I have two tables that has different information.
One table has materials, min and max. The other one has materials, quantity, location, state and date.

i have these two statements

```
select COUNT(*) from table1 where Material = '123456789' and state = 1
select Min from Materiales where Material = '123456789'
```

The first statement gives me the number of rows i have with that material. e.g. 10

The second one gives me the Min(Minimum) number e.g. 6

Now, what i need is that when the quantity of rows are equal or less than the Min number, the textbox i have for that material gets red.

Is this possible?

Best regards

Marcelo.-

Answer (score 3):

Definitely you can do that by using BackColor Property of textbox

```
if(NumOfRows <= MinNumOfRows)
{
    textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

this will color the textbox's background red.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You can use if statement. You will need a code block like that:

```
var sql1 = "select COUNT(*) from table1 where Material = '123456789' and state = 1";
var sql2 = "select Min from Materiales where Material = '123456789'";

int rowcount = executesql(sql1);
int min_value = executesql(sql2);

if(rowcount <= min_value)
{
   textbox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```